# How to modify a state variable passed with useContext (not the setState modify, more like a visual edit)

Tags: reactjs, web3js, use-context

I am using setState in the App.js, and i have passed it to a child component with useContext. I want to modify that state in the child component. Not like the setState way, but changing its decimals, making an Identicon from its string etc. However React is giving me memory leak warning, and i couldn't find a solution.

For example

```
- const [ethBalance, setEthBalance] =  useState(0); 

- <BuyContext.Provider value={{ethBalance, tokenBalance, buyToken, web3}}><BuyComponent /></BuyContext.Provider>
```

in the `BuyComponent`  i would like to change the balance from wei to eth;

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { BuyContext } from '../App.js'

const { ethBalance, tokenBalance, buyToken, web3 } = useContext(BuyContext);

Balance: {window.web3.utils.fromWei({ethBalance})}
```

Some of the relevant codes.

I could not make it recognize `web3` functions as well, although i passed it. It say `web3` is undefined.

Comment: Can you show how you are currently trying to edit the useContext in the child component currently, that is giving you the memory leak error?

Comment: `<div>Balance: {window.web3.utils.fromWei({ethBalance})} </div>` like that for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try setting the balance in the child component as a useEffect function?

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { BuyContext } from '../App.js'

const { ethBalance, tokenBalance, buyToken, web3 } = useContext(BuyContext);
const [balance, setBalance] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (ethBalance) {
        setBalance(window.web3.utils.fromWei({ethBalance}));
    }
}, [ethBalance]);

console.log(balance);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that looks sensible. However i'm having `web3` error, could not try that out. That's my second problem unfortunately `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromWei' of undefined` . It does not recognize `web3`